# Can you help me to fix this bug?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am testing djangorestframework and there is an error. Can anybody help me?

[image]

python version: 3.9.1

django version: 2.2.13

Comment: Can you share your manage.py

Comment: See my comment, your python is higher than what Django support

Comment: Thank you. How can I decide Django version for my python. Python version is 3.9.1

Comment: Hello @sirius provide full **Traceback**.

Comment: Hello, Ankit. Error is as given in the snapshot. There is one more line and it's this "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1):

Your Python version is 3.9, Django support Python 3.9 only on the 2.2.17 [See the release note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/2.2/) so you need to upgrade to a least the 2.2.17.

For example :

```
pip install Django==2.2.17
```

Comment: Thank you. You reply have the point and upgraded. But it's not still working.

Comment: What error are you having ?

Comment: Just the same error. If you don't mind, I hope to talk about this through slack. Can you leave me your email address plaese?

Answer (score 0):

Use python3 manage.py migrate

Ideally if you are using multiple versions of python and django os the latest version, this comes up